# Encryption of text using a matrix

Tags: java, matrix

[![скрин][1]][1][[image: scrreen]2]I need to give it a look like the one on the screen, but I'm sure I did it wrong.
The point is that there is a string str, in this case it is (i love my mother very big and love car) and after entering this string in the matrix you need to divide it into groups of 5 letters.
The result should be as follows (irlyo bvieg maynm dolto hveer cvaer).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        String[][] matrixA;
        matrixA = new String[2][15];

        matrixA[0][0] = "i";
        matrixA[0][1] = "l";
        matrixA[0][2] = "o";
        matrixA[0][3] = "v";
        matrixA[0][4] = "e";
        matrixA[0][5] = "m";
        matrixA[0][6] = "y";
        matrixA[0][7] = "m";
        matrixA[0][8] = "o";
        matrixA[0][9] = "t";
        matrixA[0][10] = "h";
        matrixA[0][11] = "e";
        matrixA[0][12] = "r";
        matrixA[0][13] = "v";
        matrixA[0][14] = "e";
        matrixA[1][0] = "r";
        matrixA[1][1] = "y";
        matrixA[1][2] = "b";
        matrixA[1][3] = "i";
        matrixA[1][4] = "g";
        matrixA[1][5] = "a";
        matrixA[1][6] = "n";
        matrixA[1][7] = "d";
        matrixA[1][8] = "l";
        matrixA[1][9] = "o";
        matrixA[1][10] = "v";
        matrixA[1][11] = "e";
        matrixA[1][12] = "c";
        matrixA[1][13] = "a";
        matrixA[1][14] = "r";


        for (int i = 0; i < matrixA.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrixA[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(matrixA[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the input `String` always 30 characters?  What is the purpose of your program?  Do you have to produce the chart or just the final result?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Why not just assume that the string is not always 30 characters? Why does it matter what the purpose of the program is? Ivan didn't ask for the chart to be produced, I believe it was just to aid the reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at the bottom you have two for-loops that loop over the matrix. All we need to do in order to achieve the algorithm you're asking for is to loop over the matrix but with the dimensions flipped. Then check if it's time to add a space by using modulus. Try out this function, let me know if you have any questions.

```
public static String getGroups(String[][] matrix, int groupSize) {
    String output = "";
    int matrixWidth = matrix.length;
    int matrixHeight = matrix[0].length;
    
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrixHeight; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixWidth; j++) {
            k++;
            output += matrix[j][i];
            if(k % groupSize == 0) output += " ";
        }
    }
    
    return output;
}
```

All you need to do is call getGroups, pass in matrixA and pass in a groupSize of 5. This is what it would look like: `System.out.println(getGroups(matrixA, 5));`

Also a heads up, you're missing a double-quotation mark (") on this line `matrixA[0][10] = h";`

This means the complete code should look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] matrixA;
    matrixA = new String[2][15];

    matrixA[0][0] = "i";
    matrixA[0][1] = "l";
    matrixA[0][2] = "o";
    matrixA[0][3] = "v";
    matrixA[0][4] = "e";
    matrixA[0][5] = "m";
    matrixA[0][6] = "y";
    matrixA[0][7] = "m";
    matrixA[0][8] = "o";
    matrixA[0][9] = "t";
    matrixA[0][10] = "h";
    matrixA[0][11] = "e";
    matrixA[0][12] = "r";
    matrixA[0][13] = "v";
    matrixA[0][14] = "e";
    matrixA[1][0] = "r";
    matrixA[1][1] = "y";
    matrixA[1][2] = "b";
    matrixA[1][3] = "i";
    matrixA[1][4] = "g";
    matrixA[1][5] = "a";
    matrixA[1][6] = "n";
    matrixA[1][7] = "d";
    matrixA[1][8] = "l";
    matrixA[1][9] = "o";
    matrixA[1][10] = "v";
    matrixA[1][11] = "e";
    matrixA[1][12] = "c";
    matrixA[1][13] = "a";
    matrixA[1][14] = "r";

    for (int i = 0; i < matrixA.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixA[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(matrixA[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    
    System.out.println(getGroups(matrixA, 5));
}

public static String getGroups(String[][] matrix, int groupSize) {
    String output = "";
    int matrixWidth = matrix.length;
    int matrixHeight = matrix[0].length;
    
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrixHeight; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixWidth; j++) {
            k++;
            output += matrix[j][i];
            if(k % groupSize == 0) output += " ";
        }
    }
    
    return output;
}
```

Comment: How can you show the result only once?

Comment: What do you mean? It does only return the result once?

Comment: not 5 times, and I want 1 time calf

Comment: Have you tried running the function? The 5 in my example is just the group size, this means you could change it to be a group size of 6, 2, 10, etc.

Comment: @Ivan Kolisnik, According to your **own** post: `The result should be as follows (irlyo bvieg maynm dolto hveer cvaer)`. This is **exactly** what the code above produces. And what is `calf`?

Comment: I want to display the encoded text only once

Comment: This line (irlyo bvieg maynm dolto hveer cvaer)

Comment: When you run the function how many times does it "display" it for you?

Comment: I added the compilation result below

Comment: Make sure you didn't call the function inside that for-loop at the bottom. Make sure it is outside of the for-loop, that way it will only call once.

Comment: Then my matrix changes appearance. Look at the screen above.Output is no longer in columns

Comment: how to fix is't?Do you know?

Comment: Don't delete the for loops, just call the function after the for loops. I've edited my answer to show you exactly what the main method should look like.

Answer (score 1):

@IvanKolisnik, To process the string you specified: `i love my mother very big and love car` and use the **`getGroups()`** method provided by **@MorganS42** you would need to do something like this:

***Create the Matrix (like the sample you had shown)***

```
String strg = "i love my mother very big and love car";
strg = strg.replaceAll("\\s+", ""); // Remove all whitespaces!
int columns = strg.length() / 2;
String[][] matrix = new String[2][columns];

int indexer = 0;
for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < matrix[row].length; column++) {
        matrix[row][column] = Character.toString(strg.charAt(indexer));
        indexer++;
    }
}

// Display Current Generated Matrix...
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
        if (matrix[i][j].isEmpty()) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

System.out.println();
```

***Display the encrypted line (as per your specs):***

```
/* Get the desired grouping from the generated 
   matrix and displsy it to console...     */
String encryptedString = getGroups(matrix, 5);
System.out.println(encryptedString);
```

***Output to console should be***:

```
ilovemymotherve
rybigandlovecar

irlyo bvieg maynm dolto hveer cvaer
```

Consequently...if the string to encrypt was:

```
I love my mother very big but I love my car bigger!
```

The console output would be:

```
Ilovemymotherverybig
butIlovemycarbigger!

Ibluo tvIel moyvm eomty hcear rvbei rgygb eirg!
```

Comment: Let me know if this works for you then I will delete this post.

Comment: Can you please write what it will look like.  complete code